# How to execute blocking code in a non-blocking Handler in Undertow?

Tags: java, asynchronous, undertow

As described in a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092146/undertow-how-to-do-non-blocking-io), when using Undertow, all the processing should be done in a dedicated Worker thread pool, which looks like this:

```
public class Start {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
        .addListener(8080, "localhost")
        .setHandler(new HttpHandler() {
          public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange exchange)
              throws Exception {
            if (exchange.isInIoThread()) {
              exchange.dispatch(this);
              return;
            }
            exchange.getResponseHeaders()
                    .put(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
            exchange.getResponseSender()
                    .send("Hello World");
          }
        })
        .build();
    server.start();
  }
}
```

I understand that `BlockingHandler` can be used for explicitly telling Undertow to schedule the request on a dedicated thread pool for blocking requests. We could adapt the above example by wrapping the `HttpHandler` in an instance of `BlockingHandler`, like so:

```
        .setHandler(new BlockingHandler(new HttpHandler() {
```

This would work for calls that we know are always blocking.

However, in case some code is non-blocking most of the time, but sometimes requires a blocking call, how to turn *that* blocking call into a non-blocking one? For example, if the requested value is present in cache, the following code would not block (it's just fetching from some `Map<>`), but if it's not, it has to be fetched from the database.

```
public class Start {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
        .addListener(8080, "localhost")
        .setHandler(new HttpHandler() {
          public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange exchange)
              throws Exception {
            if (exchange.isInIoThread()) {
              exchange.dispatch(this);
              return;
            }
            if (valueIsPresentInCache(exchange)) {
              return valueFromCache;  // non-blocking
            } else {
              return fetchValueFromDatabase(); // blocking!!!
            }
          }
        })
        .build();
    server.start();
  }
}
```

According to the [docs](http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.4.0/index.html#blocking-io), there is a method `HttpServerExchange.startBlocking()`, but according to JavaDoc, unless you really need to use the input stream, this call is still a blocking one.

> Calling this method puts the exchange in blocking mode, and creates a
>   BlockingHttpExchange object to store the streams. When an exchange is
>   in blocking mode the input stream methods become available, other than
>   that there is presently no major difference between blocking an
>   non-blocking modes

How would one turn this blocking call into a non-blocking one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way is to actually do the logic in the IO thread, if it is non-blocking. Otherwise, delegate the request to a dedicated thread, like this:

```java
public class Example {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
        .addListener(8080, "localhost")
        .setHandler(new HttpHandler() {
          public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange exchange)
              throws Exception {

            if (valueIsPresentInCache(exchange)) {
              getValueFromCache();  // non-blocking, can be done from IO thread           
            } else {

              if (exchange.isInIoThread()) {
                exchange.dispatch(this);
                // we return immediately, otherwise this request will be
                // handled both in IO thread and a Worker thread, throwing
                // an exception
                return;
              }

              fetchValueFromDatabase(); // blocking!!!

            }
          }
        })
        .build();
    server.start();
  }
}
```